# How to count ALL WooCommerce stock?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone help me count all WooCommerce stock levels? My code below counts the Woocommerce products post type which in my case currently returns 6 as there are only 6 products. Is it possible to count all the stock levels from all products & their variations so theoretically this would return a number more close to 500.

```
function uce_number_events_tickets() {
$count_events = wp_count_posts( $post_type = 'event' );
$count_products = wp_count_posts( $post_type = 'product' );
echo ('<div id="uce-counter">We currently have ' . '<span>' . $count_events->publish . '</span>' . ' events listed with ' . '&amp; ' . '<span>' . $count_products->publish . '</span>' . ' tickets available to buy!</div>');
}
add_shortcode('uce_number_events_tickets', 'uce_number_events_tickets');
```